# Creating an "After Insert" Trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers, insert

Please have a look at the below diagram

[image]

I need to write a Trigger in `Ongoing_Portfolio` where it automatically updates `Ongoing_Fees` after `Insert` operation.

The `Portfolio.Other_Fee` is a percentage, while `Ongoing_Fees.Other_Fee = Ongoing_Portfolio.Cash_Value * Portfolio.Other_Fee`.

Please note the `idPortfolio` in all 3 tables. What happens here is after user Inserted data into `Ongoing_Portfolio`, it scans for the related `Portfolio` using `idPortfolio`. Then it grabs the `Other_Fee` from the related portfolio and insert the data into Ongoing_Fees.

Below is the Trigger I wrote, but I couldn't write the insert method to do the `Other_Fee`.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `Ongoing_Portfolio_AINS` AFTER INSERT ON `Ongoing_Portfolio` FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO Ongoing_Fees (idPortfolio,Other_Fee)
VALUES
(New.idPortfolio, )
```

How can I complete this Trigger?

**example:**

```
Portfolio.idPortfolio = 1
Portfolio.Other_Fee = 10%
```

Now I insert data into `Ongoing_Portfolio`

```
Ongoing_Portfolio.idPortfolio = 1
Ongoing_Portfolio.Cash_Value = 1000
```

Now, the `trigger` has triggered, so the data in Ongoing_Fees should be

```
Ongoing_Fees.idPortfolio = 1
Ongoing_Fees.Other_Fee = 100
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what effects should occur after an example insert into ongoing_portfolio

Comment: Please consider the exact data type `DECIMAL` for fees instead of approximate ones like `DOUBLE`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
INSERT INTO Ongoing_Fees (idPortfolio,Other_Fee)
    select New.idPortfolio, p.other_fee
    from Portfolio p
    where p.idPortfolio = New.idPortfolio;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply..But, errr..Where is the `Values` part?

Comment: @Sniper That's (INSERT INTO ... SELECT syntax)[https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-select.html]. No need for `VALUES`.

Comment: @Sniper . . . `Values` is not needed for `insert`.  In fact, `insert . . . select` does everything that `insert . . . values` does, and more.

Comment: err..OK, It is actually your `p.other_fee` should be `New.Cash_Value * p.Other_Fee` right? (You can see my updated question which has an example if you are confused...